# The set of variables used for weighing-up changes the resulting estimates

Tags: r, survey

When comparing the effects of the set of variables passed to the `svyby` function on the resulting estimates and standard errors, I discovered that weighing up a single variable and two variables yields the same estimates, but weighing up multiple variables yields a significantly lower estimate than the other two methods.

What is the reason for that, and how can I avoid this from happening?

Link to the dataset: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xqFxUBLZifaz57yvoNFOcvhBDGuHuSMq

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(survey)

load("des2004small.RData")

weighUp <- function(variables) {
  svyby(formula = make.formula(variables), by = ~statefip, 
        design = des2004small,  
        FUN = svytotal, na.rm = TRUE)
}

# Weigh up a single variable:
dfstate2004_singleVariable = weighUp(c("race_acs"))
# Weigh up two variables:
dfstate2004_twoVariables = weighUp(c("race_acs", "cvap_acs"))
# Weigh up multiple variables:
dfstate2004_multipleVariables = weighUp(c("race_acs", "cit_acs", 
                                          "educ_acs", "unemployed_acs", "labforce_acs", "poverty_acs", "cvap_acs"))

# Compare the three diffent methods:
comparison2004 = dfstate2004_singleVariable %>% 
  inner_join(dfstate2004_twoVariables, by = "statefip", suffix = c(".single", ".two")) %>%
  inner_join(dfstate2004_multipleVariables, by = "statefip", suffix = c("", ".multiple"))

race_acswhite2004 = comparison2004 %>% 
  select(statefip, 
         single = race_acswhite.single, 
         two = race_acswhite.two, 
         multiple = race_acswhite)
race_acswhite2004
```

Here are the resulting differing estimates:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|   statefip  single     two multiple |
+-------------------------------------+
| 1        1 3084123 3084123  2128346 |
| 2        2  427008  427008   277075 |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables in the 'multiple' table have missing values, and `svytotal` drops any observations with missing values on *any* of the variables it is analysing. Well, by default it gives `NA` results,  but if you ask it to drop missing values with `na.rm=TRUE` it drops them and the whole observation.